# Array consisting of the values inside of another array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have  an array that looks like this:

```
int map[21][28] =
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};
```

How can I create a smaller array consisting of the values inside that array..?
A bit like this:

```
int zoomedMap[7][7] =
{

    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
};
```

I don't know if this helps, but:

- I know the exact dimensions of both arrays
- I want it to be possible to move the smaller arrays position, preferably by just changing an X/Y value

Comment: If you want this to be efficient, and referential, you don't need an array; you need a pointer, an (X,Y) coordinate tuple, a width+height tuple, and some math.

Comment: I have no idea how to do all that. Could you post an answer with some pseudo-code or just actual code?

Comment: Sure thing. It's simple, and like a regular array in C/C++, it isn't going to stop you from shooting yourself, but it should at least give you an idea or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do it statically with loops:

```
const int pos_x = 6, pos_y = 7, size_x = 7, size_y = 7;

int newMap[size_x][size_y] = {0};

for( int i = pos_x; i != pos_x+size_x; ++i ) {
    for( int j = pos_y; j != pos_y+size_y; ++j) {
        newMap[i-pos_x][j-pos_y] = map[i][j];
    }
}
```

Although this isn't very safe, and difficult to get working dynamically.
You might want to either write a matrix-wrapper class with the functions you desire; or find one that already exists and extend it (I'd start looking into the STL or Boost for an existing matrix class)

Answer (score 1):

In what is hopefully obvious, your sub-array is literally nothing more than a "block" of data (with some interesting partitioning) *within* your main array. Assuming you are checking your boundaries and will NOT allow an out of bounds condition to happen, you can simulate your sub-array using pointer math and some basic info about your main array.

- The block will *always* be some `[row][column]` offset from the `[0][0]` location, so we need those values (row and column).
- The block has fixed width such that `column+width` does not exceed your main array width. We need that width.
- The block has fixed height such that `row+height` does not exceed your main array height. We need that height.
- I hope it obvious we need the base address that is the main array (in your case `map`).

This is probably best demonstrated by example. The following is NOT some end-all solution. It will likely not even address 1/10th of the need you're going to have. Rather, it is intended to offer you an idea on how you can do this using only a pointer, some offsets, some sizes, and a little arithmetic to get what you're looking for. There is *nothing* stopping you from exceeding limits that may be harmful (just like a plain array), so be cautious.

```
// internal rerefential to a submatrix in a larger fixed matrix.
template<typename T>
class Sub2D
{
public:
    template<size_t R, size_t C>
    Sub2D(T(&ar)[R][C], int top, int left, int height, int width)
    : parent(ar[0])
    , row(top)
    , col(left)
    , max_row(R)
    , max_col(C)
    {
        if ((row+width) >= R || (col+height) >= C)
            throw std::out_of_range("");
    }

    // retrieve our subrow offset into the main 2D array
    T* operator [](size_t n)
    {
        // enable at your desire, but as Alex pointed out, all
        // the standard containers let you shoot yourself in the
        // foot with this operator. why not this one too =P
        //if (row+n >= max_row)
        //    throw std::out_of_range("");

        return parent + ((row+n)*max_col + col);
    }

private:
    T* parent;
    size_t row, col;
    size_t max_row, max_col;
};
```

Used like this, assuming your array in your question is the one we're basing:

```
int main()
{
    // take the submatrix & [6][7] that is 7x7 in dimension.
    Sub2D<int> sub(map, 6,7, 7,7);
    for (size_t i=0;i<7;++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0;j<7;++j)
            cout << sub[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // update an element at location [1][1] of our sub-matrix.
    sub[1][1] = 9;

    // reprint the *entire* main array. it better have updated.
    for (size_t i=0;i<sizeof(map)/sizeof(map[0]);++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0;j<sizeof(map[0])/sizeof(map[0][0]);++j)
            cout << map[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output.

```
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 9 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note the 9 now sitting right where we expect it.

There is obviously a LOT more you can add to such a template class, including better range checking, moving your pointer, snap-shotting into other memory buffers, etc, but the point is for basic get-me-this sub matrix a pointer and a few offsets are hard to beat, especially for performance.

Comment: Looks good, but I don't think operator[] should throw an exception, leave that to at(). operator[] should be unsafe, but efficient.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain good point about []. Updated shortly. Like i said. really anorexic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of Boost's [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) module. It provides Matrix and MatrixRange classes, which are exactly what you are looking for.

In essence, the `zoomedMap` should just be an intelligent pointer into the larger matrix, which understands how to dereference and get the correct result.

Comment: So, you have a deep understanding of column-major or row-major ordering of matrices? You understand the limitations on C++ pointers when used in matrix operations?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, this may suffice:

```
int (*zoomedMap)[28] = reinterpret_cast<int (*)[28]>(&map[X][Y]);
```

This gives you an identifier you can use as if it were a two-dimensional array: `zoomedMap[i][j]`. You can easily move the zoomed map within the larger array by assigning a new address to it.

It depends on your C++ implementation allowing a pointer to float to be cast to a pointer to an array of float, provided all references remain within the original array. This is common.

It leaves `zoomedMap` pointing to the same memory as `map`. Thus, you cannot change one without changing the other. If you want to do that, you would need to make a copy.